# Big O of fragment of code with "in" operation on list

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o

What would be Big O of following fragment of code?

```
with open(file_name) as f:
    for word in f:
        w = word.rstrip()
        k = ''.join(sorted(w)).lower()
        if k in words:
            words[k].append(w)
        else:
            words[k] = [w]
```

Comment: What is your question, specifically?

Comment: There are several parts of the code that have influence on the time complexity. `sorted()` for example should have far more than `in`.

Comment: @KlausD. Can I say with fair degree of certainty that this is not O(N)?

Comment: The sorting should have an average complexity of `O(n log n)`. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort for details.

Comment: I think over all complexity is O(N) + O(n log n) so it is O(n log n)

Answer (score 1):

`x in alist` is `O(n)`, but this code isn't performing membership testing on a `list`; `words` looks to be a `dict`, and membership testing in `dict`'s keys (or in a `set`) is `O(1)` (technically, worst case could be `O(n)`, but it's average case `O(1)` and they put some effort into thwarting even intentional attempts to cause collisions).

This code could be simplified a bit using `collections.defaultdict` though, so creating `list`s is done implicitly when a non-existent key is looked up:

```
import collections

words = collections.defaultdict(list)
with open(file_name) as f:
    for word in f:
        w = word.rstrip()
        words[''.join(sorted(w)).lower()].append(w)
```

If you want uniqueness (though it would lose ordering), you just change to `defaultdict(set)` and change `append` to `add`. If you need uniqueness and ordering, `collections.OrderedDict` can (mostly) work as an ordered `set`:

```
import collections

words = collections.defaultdict(collections.OrderedDict)
with open(file_name) as f:
    for word in f:
        w = word.rstrip()
        # True is placeholder, any value will do if you're using in tests properly
        words[''.join(sorted(w)).lower()][w] = True
```

Comment: `words` is indexed by a string, it can't be a list.

Comment: @JohnDoLittle: `words` is most definitely not a `list`. You're using a `str` to perform lookups in it, if it's a `list`, you'd be getting repeated `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`; it's a `dict` of `list`s, or some esoteric (non-builtin) type. Since you never test membership in the values of the `dict` (which are `list`s), you're never paying any `O(n)` lookup costs.

Answer (score 0):

The `k in words` would have linear complexity, that is, O(len(words)), *if* `words` *were a list*.

It looks like `words` is a `dict`, though, since `words[k]` apparently indexes it over a string, something that a list won't accept.

For a `dict`, access time can be seen as constant, O(1), both for searching (`in`) and updating. (This is amortized time.)

Comment: What would be over all complexity, thank in to account the whole fragment?

Comment: The whole piece reads a file so the time is going to be dominated by I/O. It is obviously linear in the number of characters read, provided that you don't have overly long words. The algorithmically slowest piece is the call to `sorted` which is O(n * log(n)) where n = `len(w)`. If all your words are much shorter than the text as a whole, it can just be considered a constant, and the whole piece is O(length of file).  If you happen to have a text consisting of 2 or 3 super-long words, the performance will be dominated by `sorted` (log-linear), but it's a marginal case.

Comment: Lets break it down, you complexity of reading N lines form a file is O(N) and complexity of comparing sorted(w) against n - 1 is O(n log n). Hence dominant operation in my opinion would be sorted(w), which is O(n log n).

Comment: This depends on what _n_ are we talking about. The whole thing is _O(k * s)_, where _k_ is the number of characters (we scan each exactly once), and _s_ is the complexity of analyzing each word (splitting to words is _O(1)_ per character). If _w_ = len(longest word) << _k_, we can assume _s_ ≤ _O(w log w)_, because no word is longer than _w_. Thus _s_ ≤ constant, or _s_ is O(1). If, OTOH, _w_ is comparable to _k_, we have only a few words in the text _for any value of k_, <=> words get longer as the length of text grows, but their number _c_ stays about the same, we have _O(k * log (k/c))_.